# Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException

Tags: .net, animation, xna, sprite, monogame

So I'm creating a commercial game with monogame and monogame extended and one of the biggest thing in monogame extended is it's ease of creating animations with sprite sheets but whenever I try to load a sprite sheet I get this error: Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException: 'Could not find ContentTypeReader Type. Please ensure the name of the Assembly that contains the Type matches the assembly in the full type name: MonoGame.Extended MonoGame.Extended.Animations.SpriteFactory.SpriteFactoryFileReader, MonoGame.Extended.Animations (MonoGame.Extended MonoGame.Extended.Animations.SpriteFactory.SpriteFactoryFileReader, MonoGame.Extended.Animations)'
I also have to mention this wasn't an issue until I downloaded .NET sdk version 7 I don't think it should make a problem but because of the timing it might cause an issue.

How can I fix this also this issue wasn't there before it was working great until one day I saw nothing of my game is working due to this.

I removed all the nugest packages and re-installed them didn't work - created a new project just for testing and the same issue there as well

Comment: what are you using to create the sprite sheet? what are the creation parameters you are using

Comment: The software monogame extended have created which is called sprite factory https://github.com/craftworkgames/SpriteFactory

Comment: What platform are you targeting?  Monogame uses reflection for assembly resolution, and the mscore changed names causing this type of problem.  There is probably a .config or .json file somewhere allowing the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall .Net 7.

That would be the simplest solution.

The other would be to modify all of the json build files not to target the latest .Net release.